# radius of circles in leaflet app to be driven by the selectInput

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I am trying to make the radius of my circle markers in this Shiny leaflet app be driven by the `selectInput` variable.

The dropdown has three values, "Week.1", "Week.2" and "Week.3", which are all numeric vectors (of large dollar revenue values in millions) in the d at the bottom of this question.

```
selectInput("weekView", "Week's Revenue:",
          c("1" = "Week.1",
            "2" = "Week.2",
            "3" = "Week.3")),
```

I am currently loading `Week.1` and get thr result. I wNt the input to change the weeks and react with the corresponding $ on the map.
When I try and use input$weekView instead of the static `~(Week.1)`, I get errors as it is "Week.1".  I've tried using quote = False in place to remove them before the radius is calculated but I'm failing to find the right place to do so...

```
leaflet(data = P) %>%
  addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
  addCircleMarkers(~Long, ~Lat, popup = ~Week.1,
                   radius = ~(Week.1)/40000,
                   stroke = FALSE, 
                   fillOpacity = 0.5)
```

Can any one advise on how best to go about this? What I want to say is
`radius = input$weekView/40000`

All the script:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)   

ui <- fluidPage(

  selectInput("weekView", "Week's Revenue:",
              c("1" = "Week.1",
                "2" = "Week.2",
                "3" = "Week.3")), 

  leafletOutput("mymap"),
  p()
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {


  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({

    x <- input$weekView

    P<- read.csv("Lebara_weeks_rev4.csv")

    as.numeric(P$Long)
    as.numeric(P$Lat)
    as.character(P$Week.1)

    P$Week.1 <- as.numeric(gsub(",","",P$Week.1))
    P$Week.2 <- as.numeric(gsub(",","",P$Week.2))
    P$Week.3 <- as.numeric(gsub(",","",P$Week.3))

    long <- P$Long
    Lat <- P$Lat

    leaflet(data = P) %>%
      addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
      addCircleMarkers(~Long, ~Lat, popup = ~Week.1,
                       radius = ~(Week.1)/40000,
                       stroke = FALSE, 
                       fillOpacity = 0.5)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Head of the df = P

```
    > head(P)
    group      Lat      Long        Country  Week.1  Week.2  Week.3  Week.4
1 178.100 55.37805 -3.435973 United Kingdom 649,613 665,147 640,732 649,642
2 174.890 51.16569 10.451526        Germany 117,766 120,402 104,167  91,157
3 144.100 46.22764  2.213749         France 135,784 117,759 109,337 101,873
4 174.211 52.13263  5.291266    Netherlands 403,950 397,438 377,855 389,345
5 174.990 40.46367 -3.749220          Spain  94,472  95,742  88,313  86,400
6 178.600 56.26392  9.501785        Denmark  70,094  72,487  67,597  66,769
```

Thanks!
Pete

I used tidyr and subsetWeek1 <- P[1:7,] then made variables for the `subsetWeek1$value/40000` to make them small enough for the radius values) of those subsets.  I tried to make the selectInput  1 = subsetWeek1$value, 2 = subsetWeek2$value and 3 = subsetWeek3$value...

```
library(tidyr)
P <- tidyr::gather(P, week, value, Week.1:Week.3)

subsetWeek1 <- P[1:7,]
subsetWeek2 <- P[8:14,]
subsetWeek3 <- P[15:21,]

Week1val <- subsetWeek1$value
Week2val <- subsetWeek2$value
Week3val <- subsetWeek3$value
```

This doesn't seem to pick up the `selectInput` value and change the map.  There are no markers on the map and no errors provided.  Could it be the scale of the circles makes them invisible?  In the non-app version they are OK.

Comment: You need to add enough data to your question to be [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: @alistaire  how is this now? All code. A sample of the df and more of an explanation.

Comment: Better, but everything is hardcoded to week 1. Gather to long form (e.g. `tidyr::gather(P, week, value, Week.1:Week.4)`) so you can easily subset `P` within your server function with the information from the select input. Side note: Load and clean your data outside of your server function, so it only gets done once.

Comment: Thanks, @alistaire.  I'll try that.  (The hardcoded version was because I could not get any other to work).  I've only been doing this for a few weeks now so grateful for all the help on SO! tidyr looks cool.  I was doing that work in xls before importing...  Thanks for the outsider server tip.

Comment: Please out me out of my misery:

Comment: I've updated the question with where I got to.  No errors in the result doesn't help me know what I am doing wrong.  I get a map with no markers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, you just need to update variable names and clean up a bit. Generally, if you're repeating the same line with a slightly different parameter, there's a better way. An option, using `tidyr` for `gather` and `extract_numeric`:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyr)
library(leaflet)

P <- read.csv("Lebara_weeks_rev4.csv")

# do munging that won't change based on input here
P2 <- gather(P, week, value, Week.1:Week.4)    # gather to long form
P2$value <- extract_numeric(P2$value)    # convert to numeric

ui <- fluidPage(
    selectInput("weekView", "Week's Revenue:",
                c("1" = "Week.1",
                  "2" = "Week.2",
                  "3" = "Week.3",
                  "4" = "Week.4")),

    leafletOutput("mymap")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
        # do munging dependent on input here
        P3 <- P2[P2$week == input$weekView, ]    # subset based on input

        leaflet(data = P3) %>%
            addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
            addCircleMarkers(lng = ~Long, lat = ~Lat, 
                             popup = ~format(value, big.mark = ','),    # reinsert commas
                             radius = ~value/40000,
                             stroke = FALSE, 
                             fillOpacity = 0.5)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You're a gentleman and a scholar, mate!  That worked a treat.

Comment: With dynamically changing "value"  how would I set colour to say: if the current value selected is less than the previous value, colour = "red", else "green".  e.g.  if "week.2" < "week.1", addCircleMarkers( colour = "red").  week.1 would always be green to start.

Comment: You can map `fillColor` (careful, `fill` is boolean here, unlike ggplot) to an `ifelse` for a simple option: `fillColor = ~ifelse(value > c(0, value[-nrow(P2)]), 'green', 'red')`, but that's entirely based on location in the data.frame, which will make some week 1 values inaccurate. A more thorough option would be to add a color column to `P2` using your favorite means of grouping, e.g. base's `ave`, dplyr's `group_by` and `mutate`, or data.table's `:=` and `by`.

Comment: Regarding the subsequent comment, pass what value back and forth between what? You don't have anything that complicated yet that you can't handle with the server's normal handling of `input` and `output`.